# jQueryUI's resizeable() causes resize events to fire to all ancestors... why?

Tags: jquery-ui, events, resize

I created a couple of nested divs, the inner horizontally resizeable, the outer vertically resizeable. I have it such that resizing a parent div (or the window) causes the children to resize.

However, I'm finding that when a child div is resized, it's ancestors all rx the resize event even *even when their sizes don't change*.

I'm using Chrome 18.0 on Win7.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/m95Ha/ 
Resize the red & cyan sides and the window, and watch the chars in the black div. For example, resizing the cyan side horizontally causes an 'i' ('#inner' resize event), an 'o' 'i' ('#outer' resize event), *and* a 'w' (window resize event).
I wouldn't have expected the 'o' or the 'w'.

Is this a jQuery thing, or a Chrome thing, or perhaps the HTML/DOM standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior of jQuery UI; the resize method bubbles like normal events.  You can  filter out resize events that occur on non jQuery UI resizable widgets with the following if necessary:

```
$('whatever').bind('resize', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('ui-resizable')) {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

There's some relevant discussion in this question as well - [jQuery UI resizable fire window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494378/jquery-ui-resizable-fire-window-resize-event).